# Validation error messages for integers, how to?

Tags: python, validation

I've been working on a sleep calculator that needs a validation error message. The code that I need to validate is:

```
hourspernight = int(input("How many hours do you sleep in a day?")
hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
input("You Sleep for",hoursperweek,"hours every week!")
```

I need to add validation so that, if the user inputs a character that is not an integer, it shows an error message asking for an integer.

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761? Also, why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Java tag removed -- come on now, no language tag spam please! Let's stick with relevant tags only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [try/except](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) inside a [while loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) which will keep asking for input until  the user enters something valid:

```
while True:
    try:
       hourspernight = int(input("How many hours do you sleep in a day?"))
       break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

hoursperweek = hourspernight * 7
print ("You Sleep for {} hours every week!".format(hoursperweek))
```

Comment: Thanks soo  much, funnily enough i found the answer half an hour ago my ones a bit different though as i added another validation wait ill show you

Comment: I presumed the second input should have been a print as you don't seen to be asking anything, you can either add a separate except block or just add it to the same